Resharper rearrange implementation of interface
I have this code:
public interface IMyClass
{
    void DoStuff();
    int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {}
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

If I apply file layout using Resharper, I get this:
public interface IMyClass
{
    int MyProperty { get; set; }
    void DoStuff();
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {}

    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

For the interface it is just as expected (properties before methods).
How do I get Resharper to also rearrange the code in the class?
Update
If the class does not implement the interface, it is rearranged as expected.
public class MyClass //: IMyClass
{
    public void DoStuff()
    { }
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

becomes
public class MyClass //: IMyClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public void DoStuff()
    { }
}

But it would be nice if it could rearrange classes with interfaces.

In your vstudio go to Extensions -> Resharper -> Options
Then go to Code Editing
Under Code Editing, go to C# -> File Layout.
There you can customize the order that ReSharper will rearrange your code.


Thank you. I have tried looking into it, but I cannot figure out how to make it rearrange both class and interface. See my update to the question.

It's not just a method and a property, it's Interface Implementations. If it's not necessary to reorder them, then it can be removed from the pattern:

